# Trying to load text file into Octave GUI into the correct format

Tags: import, octave

I have a text file that contains 10 columns separated by comas and X number of rows denoted by return.  The initial header line of the data is a string.  The first two columns are character strings while the last 8 columns are integers.  So far I have tried fscanf:

```
t1 = fscanf( test, '%c', inf );
```

which will import the data as large 1 by XXXXX character matrix and textread which imports it but does not format it correctly:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j] = textread("test.txt", "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",\
 'headerlines', 1);
```

I suspect its a simple issue of formatting the notation on textread correctly to get my desired output. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you need only the numerical data or also the text information?

Comment: use `csv2cell` from the `io` package